# show email on reset password form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a reset password form like this

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>

        <div class="form-group ">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
            </div>
            <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: resource.email, required: true, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", disabled: true %>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I want the placeholder of the field above to be the e-mail of the resource, but at this point, the `resource` only contains the field `reset_password_token` as following

```
=> #<Company id: nil, name: nil, email: nil
```

how can I show the e-mail of resource in this form?

Comment: Can you show how you set the `resource` object before passing it to this form ?

Comment: Actually, as I use devise, this is done by the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour totally makes sense if you look at devise's code:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb

The edit method:

```
def edit
  self.resource = resource_class.new
  resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
end
```

It simply creates a new resource (User for instance) and assigns the reset_password_token.

You can change this behaviour by rolling your own passwords controller.
You can do this by inheriting from devise's controller and override the edit method so that it actually loads your resource (user perhaps).

From the top of my head, something like this could work.

```
class CustomPasswordsController < Devise:: PasswordsController
  def edit
    reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
    self.resource = resource_class.find_by_reset_password_token(reset_password_token)    
  end
end
```

Then in your routes.rb, configure devise to use your custom controller

```
devise_for :users,
  :controllers => {:passwords=>"custom_passwords"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: the new devise has a method name `with_reset_password_token` that found the resource by its reset password token.
then I did this in my `PasswordsController`

```
def edit
 super
 @email = Company.with_reset_password_token(params[:reset_password_token]).email
end
```

this did the trick, but thanks a lot everyone